# AlertDialog setMessage cut off

Tags: android

I'm currently looking over some app demos given from a book and this particular app which utilizes AlertDialog is acting very strange in that it overlaps the layout with the message and its only happening when it uses this particular layout. I've tried running the app on both an emulator and real device with the same results. Any help towards solving this problem is appreciated!
[image]

Here is the dialog class.

```
    package android.bignerdranch.com.notetoself;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DialogShowNote extends DialogFragment {

    Note mNote;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_note, null);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtDescription = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        txtTitle.setText(mNote.getTitle());
        txtDescription.setText(mNote.getDescription());

        ImageView ivImportant = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImportant);
        ImageView ivTodo = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTodo);
        ImageView ivIdea = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIdea);

        if (!mNote.isImportant()){
            ivImportant.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!mNote.isTodo()){
            ivTodo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!mNote.isIdea()){
            ivIdea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Your mNote");

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }


    public void sendNoteSelected(Note noteSelected) {
        mNote = noteSelected;
    }
 }
```

And its associated layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewImportant"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_warning_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTodo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewImportant"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewImportant"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_box_outline_blank_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewIdea"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewTodo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTodo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_wb_incandescent_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewIdea"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:id="@+id/btnOK"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the textview for the cut off with the text "Your mNote" and why are there 3 imageviews?

Comment: The 3 imageviews are visible if the note has those options set which in this case is no so their currently set to View.GONE. What do you mean by the textview, this example sets the message by passing in a regular string literal.

Comment: what is the cut off thing on the top of the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this same thing myself from the same book and getting the same results. I know my New Note Dialog works just fine but the Show Note Dialog is doing this.

From what I've found looking around, this happens due to the way some devices handle the setMessage call on AlertDialogs. They just cut off text like this. A work around is to actually put in a Plain TextView widget in the layout above the other widgets that says "Your mNote."

Unfortunately it just looks like its one of those things you have to plan for and not just have the setMessage function handle it.

Change

```
builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Your mNote");
```

to

```
builder.setView(dialogView);
```

add the Plain TextView with text "Your mNote" (I set the style of it to AlertDialog.AppCompat so it's a bit similar) on the XML for Show Note.

and then format everything else beneath it.

I believe this is also what rmanalo was getting at with his "where is the textview for the cut off..."